# Installing Python 3 Docker Ubuntu error command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to create a dockerfile that uses Python 3.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python-pip
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libpq-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
RUN cd /var/projects/apps && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get the error  fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory when trying to install pillow in my requirements, why and I'm I installing python 3 correctly?

```
error:

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-C7CMih-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
INFO[0102] The command [/bin/sh -c cd /var/projects/app && pip install -r requirements.txt] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: I *think* you might need to call `pip3` not `pip`. However, it's probably better to use the official python3 image https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/

Comment: @AdrianMouat regarding the docker image do I install that with ``FROM ubuntu:14.04``

Comment: No, just do FROM python:3 instead of FROM ubuntu:14.04

Comment: Thank you @AdrianMouat question, how do i know what OS that runs?

Comment: It runs Debian. You can follow the chain of FROM instructions back if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `python3-pip` in your Dockerfile and then run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Do you really need ``pip3 install`` I read this was not needed anymore.

Comment: It _might_ be that if you install `pip3` only you could use just `pip install ...` Check with `which pip`  whether it points to  `usr/bin/pip3`. If so,  you don't need to specify `pip3` when installing